# What are the exact dimensions of the 2012 premium re-release of the 3.5 core rulebooks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, books

I am looking to build slipcases for the **2012 premium reprints** of the PHB, DMG, and Monster Manual, but do not have books in hand.

What are the exact dimensions of the 2012 premium reprints of the 3.5 core rulebooks? I am especially looking for thickness (which I expect to be the only value that changes), and would like accuracy to about 1mm or 1/32nd inch.

Comment: Is this the 2012 **premium** reprint, or some other 2012 edition?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie it's the premium reprint. So I think they're juuuust slightly larger than the original core books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11 1/4" tall by 8 5/8" wide by 15/16" thick for the PHB.
MM is the same but just slightly less thick at 13/16 thickness.
13/16 is the same thickness for the DMG.

This is by my hand measurements of my books.  A brand new one may be slightly less thick as mine are frequently used.

Comment: Could you remeasure your Premium books & update with "accuracy to about 1mm or 1/32nd inch" (per the question)?